# Bootstrap not loading with local files

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using `laravel` and my bootstrap is not loading when using local files, only if I use `CDN link` .  The Icons are not being show and js effects are not working.

Working:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Document</title>
   <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
</head>
```

NOT working:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="{{ URL::to('/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ URL::to('/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: if they are working when you are using cdn, maybe you didnt put your css and javascript assets in the public folder. are you using laravel 5?

Comment: You can check where the link is pointing when checking the source code of the page. You can move on from there

Comment: @Gokigooooks Yes, laravel 5.1 and it is in the public directory.

Comment: @MihkelAllorg The URL are perfect.... NO idea why this is happening =\

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro if you click on the file link in the source, does it show you the inside of the file? The server might not have the permissions to use the file. Even if you can see the inside, the server might not

Comment: @MihkelAllorg It doesnt... BUT the local JQuery is working and by clicking it's link I also can't thee se file content.

Comment: @MihkelAllorg If I Right click it and open it in 'New Tab' or "Open in resource panel". It shows the content of the file.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro if you cant see the content when you click the link then something is wrong. and its because of laravel

Answer (score 0):

you can use online library

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

or else download library and add css in css folder and jquery in js folder.both folder you keep in laravel public folder then you can link like below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/bootstrap-theme.min.css')}}">
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
```

or else

```
{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/functions.js') }}
```

change url to asset

```
<link href="{{ URL::to('/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ URL::to('/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

update

to use HTML you need to add provider in app.php

```
Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

and aliases

```
'HTML'      => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

Comment: Using `asset` didnt change anything. But using `HTML::` gave me "Class HTML not found"

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro.better you use online library because sometime bootstrap files not loading properly

Comment: I will... But I need to show something tomorrow and there has no WIFI connection... Any better solution ?

Comment: ya.you can try HTML::style or  asset().first you download latest version of bootstrap file .some time version error occures even for me also it happend

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well too.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

This was pretty stupid. As I was using laravel and `URL::to` to link my files.
I just copied the code and changed the name of the file BUT then I got this problem, I was loading a script with `<link />` instead of `<script ></script`.

```
<link href="{{ URL::to('/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and it should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::to('/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
```

pretty silly I know.